# Query condition missed key schema element: Id in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use .query to retrieve all data from the table users which have Firstname "Peter". I have created an index on the table on the partition key Id called "Id-index". but when i run the code i still get the error Query condition missed key schema element: Id.

```
 router.get('/users/query2', (req, res) => {

            var params =
             {
                 TableName: table,
                 IndexName: "Id-index",
                 KeyConditionExpression: "Firstname = :first",
                 //KeyConditionExpression: "Id  = :id",
                 //KeyConditionExpression: "Firstname = :first and Id = :id",
                 //FilterExpression: "Firstname = :first",
                 ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                     ":first": "Peter",
                     //":id": 4

                 }
             }

             let users = docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log(err);
                     handleError(err, res);
                 } else {

                     // display all users in the callback
                     // if u use handleSuccess data.Items looses its information
                     res.json({ message: 'success', statusCode: 200, data: data })
                     //handleSuccess(data.Item, res);
                 }
              });

             });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the index by the `Firstname` attribute, you should create the index on that attribute. IIUC, your index was created on the `Id` attribute, that's why it does not let you specify a condition on `Firstname` in `KeyConditionExpression`